# Combined update if not insert for multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to have a pure sql query to insert or update multiple rows. I started with working one, but for a single row:

```
WITH UPDATED_ITEMS as (
  UPDATE table SET (columnC, columnD) = ($value3, $value4) WHERE id = $value5 returning *
)
INSERT INTO table (columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD) SELECT $value1, $value2, $value3, $value4 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM updated_items)
```

Now I have changed the update condition, but don't know how to do it with insert:

```
WITH updated_items as (
  UPDATE table as m SET
    columnC = c.columnC
    columnD = c.columnD
from (values ($value3, $value4, $value5), ($value8, $value9, $value10)
) as c(columnC, columnD, id)
where c.id::int4 = m.id returning *
)
INSERT INTO table (columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD)
SELECT ($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $value5), ($value6, $value7, $value8, $value9, $value10) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM updated_items)
```

But the insert part does not work. Anyone please help?

Comment: Why not use `insert on conflict` instead?

Comment: Could I use it if the conficting column is an id as a serial?

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically need a correlation clause in the `not exists`.  Your update is referencing an `id` column, so I've added that as well.  So I think this does what you want:

```
WITH updated_items as (
  UPDATE table as m
    SET columnC = c.columnC,
        columnD = c.columnD
    FROM (VALUES ($value3, $value4, $value5),
                 ($value8, $value9, $value10)
         ) as c(columnC, columnD, id)
    WHERE c.id::int4 = m.id 
    RETURNING *
   )
INSERT INTO table (columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD)
    SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD
    FROM (VALUES ($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $value5), 
                 ($value6, $value7, $value8, $value9, $value10)
         ) c(columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD, id)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM updated_items ui WHERE ui.id = c.id::int);
```

Comment: I am relying on serial id creation, so INSERT does not have an id. If I remove last $value5, $value10 and c(id), and finally WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM updated_items); I get an error ' INSERT has more target columns than expressions')

Comment: @mjarmoc . . . The values are the same for the `insert` and `update`, and the `update` is referencing the `id`.

Comment: No, because I am inserting just 4 params into 4 columns. I cant INSERT id, because 1) it is serial on database, 2) if I am saving a new row I don't have its id. The request I send to db has as a $value5 either existing on db ID (update) or null (insert).

Comment: @mjarmoc . . . That's fine, you don't have to insert the `id`s.

Comment: thank you. However now i get an error: `error: column reference "id" is ambiguous`

Comment: @mjarmoc . . . Every column alias in this answer is fully qualified.  There should be no "ambiguous" references.